# send / receive money to/from website users in exchange for website's virtual currency, is possible with paypal?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, paypal

I have an website on asp.net-mvc, I'm thinking of using paypal for payments, is it possible to use paypal api for selling website's currency to users and buying it back ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible yes, probably a REALLY bad idea, though.

Check with Paypal whether they like your business, or you may end up with a frozen accuont faster than you can think of - including loosing all the money there.

Comment: why is it a really bad idea? Where's the problem?

Comment: As i sad - chck. their erms and condisions, for example. You break your contract with them. Sensible? WHOCCARES _ their service, their terms.